# Why won't drag event trigger on first attempt?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, drag-event

I have a javascript application in which I'm trying to handle a drag event but it requires two attempts to drag:

[image]

I want the user to be able to drag the handle on the track position bar so that they can skip ahead or go back anywhere in the track. But for some reason, the user has to attempt it twice. The first time they attempt to drag, the handle doesn't move (and the drag handler doesn't fire). On the second attempt it does.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="track-position-container">
    <div class="position-bar">
        <div class="completed-bar"></div>
        <div class="position-nob" ondrag="positionNobDragged(event)" ondragend="positionNobDragEnded(event)"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
function positionNobDragged(event) {
    const positionBar = document.querySelector('.position-bar');
    const positionNob = document.querySelector('.position-nob');
    const completedBar = document.querySelector('.completed-bar');

    const x = event.x - positionBar.offsetLeft;

    positionNob.style.left = x;
    completedBar.style.width = completedBar.style.left + x;
}

function positionNobDragEnded(event) {
    positionNobDragged(event);
}
```

You can go here to try it: http://planetshah.com/mixes/mix.html?mix=65

Does anyone know why the drag handler won't respond on the first attempt to drag the handle?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at *function positionNobDragged(event)*, there's a few bugs.

This is causing negative values when you only drag a little...

```
const x = event.x - positionBar.offsetLeft;
```

Just set your left directly...

```
const x = event.x;

positionNob.style.left = x + positionBar.offsetLeft;
```

I think it's reluctant to move at the first drag because of negative values generated.

Comment: Hi passThru, negative values shouldn't prevent drag from working as I'm able to drag the handle off the left edge of the bar on subsequent attempts (`left` should be able to take negative values). Besides, it doesn't even run that code on the first attempt. It doesn't even have a chance to set it to a negative value. On subsequent attempts, it runs without any bugs. If negative values were causing issues, shouldn't the bug exist on all attempts?